# Reference request for equivariant cohomology of G

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivariant cohomology of a group acting on itself by conjugation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20671/what-is-the-equivariant-cohomology-of-a-group-acting-on-itself-by-conjugation)

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group.  Where can one read about the equivariant cohomology $H_G^*(G)$, where $G$ acts on itself by the adjoint action?  A study of a concrete example (like SU(2)) would already be useful for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been asked (and answered) here 
[What is the equivariant cohomology of a group acting on itself by conjugation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20671/what-is-the-equivariant-cohomology-of-a-group-acting-on-itself-by-conjugation)