# What does Freed-Hopkins-Teleman say about finite groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

The third in the "Loop groups and twisted K-theory" series by FHT treats compact Lie groups without any connectedness assumptions.  I am trying to unwind what Theorem 2 of that paper (available [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/finalDirac.pdf), page 5) says for a finite group.

Theorem 2: "For regular $\tau$, there is a natural isomorphism $R^\tau(LG_s) \cong K_G^\tau(G)$ ..."

For $G$ finite, I think that the regularity condition (page 7) is empty, as it has something to do with a maximal torus of $G$.  So we can take $\tau = 0$.

On the right-hand side, that means untwisted $K$-theory, which is naturally identified with $\bigoplus_g R'(Z_G(g))$, where $R'$ denotes the Grothendieck group of finite-dimensional complex representations, and $g$ runs over conjugacy class representatives.  ($R'$ to avoid conflict with $R^\tau$, whose meaning I don't understand.)

What is on the left-hand side, when $\tau$ is zero and $G$ is finite?  It is a Grothendieck group of representations of the group of free loops in $G$, modified somehow by $\tau$ ($\tau = 0$, so not modified at all).  But I don't understand what it means.  For finite $G$, loops are constant and the Lie algebra is trivial, so from the definitions on page 5, $LG = LG_s = G$.  But it can't simply be the Grothendieck group of complex representations of $G$, that is much smaller than the right-hand side.

Comment: I would think $\tau$ is more naturally expressed as a based map $BG \to K(\mathbb{Z},4)$, so it corresponds to a group cohomology class for finite $G$.  Then the twisted K-theory is the K-theory of a (Dijkgraaf-Pasquier-Roche) twisted quantum double.

Comment: In the FHT paper, $\tau$ on the right is a parameter that twists $K$-theory, for instance a $G$-equivariant Clifford algebra on $G$.  It has a characteristic class in some combination of $H^1_G(G;\mathbf{Z}/2)$ and $H^3_G(G;\mathbf{Z})$.  Do you see a way to get from here to a class in $H^4(BG;\mathbf{Z})$?

Comment: I believe it goes the other way. Observe that $EG\times_G BG \simeq LBG$, so the idea is to transgress your class in $H^4(BG;\mathbb{Z})$ over to $H^3(LBG;\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^3_G(G;\mathbb{Z})$. Take a look at David Ben-Zvi's answer here (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20671/what-is-the-equivariant-cohomology-of-a-group-acting-on-itself-by-conjugation) for more.

Comment: Rats! I meant to write $EG\times_G G \simeq LBG$ (where $G$ is acting on itself by conjugation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Annals version of FHT III (2011). There, Theorem 2 is more carefully stated only for compact **connected** Lie $G$. I think what you want is Theorem 3 (whose statement and surrounding context are essentially the same as the '08 version of the paper you linked to):

**Theorem 3**. Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, $f \in G$. For a regular twisting $\tau$, there is a natural isomorphism $R^{\tau - \underline{\sigma}-\underline{d}}(L_f G) \stackrel{\sim}{\to} K_G^\tau([fG_1])$.

If I'm not mistaken, for $G$ finite and $\tau = 0$, Theorem 3 reduces to an isomorphism $R(Z_G(f))\cong K_G(G/Z_G(f))$. This isomorphism is, of course, an elementary observation in equivariant $K$-theory (cf. Example (ii),  p. 132, [Segal 1968](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1968__34_/PMIHES_1968__34__129_0/PMIHES_1968__34__129_0.pdf)).

Answer (score 5):

This is maybe more of a comment. Some time ago there was a paper by Simon Willerton titled ["The twisted Drinfeld double of a finite group via gerbes and finite groupoids"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503266) which tried to make sense of the statement of Freed-Hopkins-Teleman in the case of finite groups (i.e. Dijkgraaf-Witten theory).